# Object of class A cannot be create directly but only by class B

Tags: php

```
class A
{
    public function foo()
    {
    }
}

class B
{
    $a = new A;
    public function go()
    {
    }
}
```

I want A object cannot be created directly.But only by class B.
How i can do this.

Comment: He probably knows that, or he wouldn't ask.

Comment: @teresko, what precisely is he doing wrong?  How can you even tell from such a small block?

Comment: @tandu how about fact that he is creating a tight coupling between classes and he want to make it even tighter. This is against all the OOP practices.

Comment: @teresko having an object as a member of another class does not necessarily imply a tight coupling between the classes.  I'm not sure why you think he wants to make it tighter.

Comment: @tandu creating that object **inside** another class **makes it** tight coupling. Because you have no control over creating of that object, and it makes unittesting much much harder to accomplish.

Comment: "Tight coupling" implies that updates to one object will require updates to the other.  I don't see that here (not that it won't be the case, but it's impossible to tell with this code).  Instead, objects should work transparently.  Don't throw around buzzwords.  As for control over creating the object and unit testing, it depends.  You can still use reflection to create an A and test it.  There are no static methods here.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need that?

Remember - a class is a defacto factory for objects, and **the object should do things**, and it should do them with passed params and available instance variables which means you should pass everything the object needs to the constructor and you should not care about the fact that the object can be created by everybody.

Seriously.

Comment: It is on a meta level.  What is a factory (In OOP sense)?  It's something that contains instructions to create an object.  So based on that, how is a class **not** a factory (at the meta level)?  Now, on the non-meta level you can have additional factories that are inside of a class, so it really depends on the level at which you are looking at the code.  Which is one reason why straight factories are of reasonably little use in OOP (abstract factories are another story).  Anything that would be done in the factory can be pushed into the constructor.  So I can see the point @Kamil is making...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to extend an abstract class.

```
abstract class A {
    protected function foo() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public function go() {
        $this->foo();
    }
}

$obj = new B;
$obj->foo(); // error - cannot call a protected method directly
$obj->go(); // echo's "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, check [factory design pattern](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/). I think it will what you are asking for. There we will have a separate factory class for managing object creation.